# Why was I not able to connect to the WiFi in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I was new to this so please bear this weird question. 
when I open the network connections and want to connect to a network, none of the setting was editable..
How can I connect my PC (Ubuntu) to a WiFi ?

As one of them suggested to use the following command:   lspci - knn | grep Net - A3; rfkill list                  after executing that command I have got the following on the terminal as shown in below.                                                                                     06:00.0 Network controller [0280] : Intel corporation wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)                                                  subsystem: Intel corporation dual band wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470]     kernel driver in use :iwlwifi                                        07:00.0 ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL                                                                    8102E PCI Express fast ethernet controller [10ec:8136]  (rev  07)                                                                                                         0: phy0:wireless lan                                                                            softblocked:no             hard blocked: yes

Comment: When you click the Network Manager icon, do you see a list of networks to choose from? https://www.eui.eu/Images-2011/ServicesAdmin/ComputingService/eduroam/eduroamUbuntu(1).png If not, there is something else wrong; either you need a driver or the wireless switch is set to turn off the wireless radio.

Comment: Thankyou @chili555.  But I cant even see the network manager icon on top right menu bar.   When I search for network connections it is showing me a dialog box where we can create any network. But all those options are being uneditable. What can I do now?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following command in Terminal: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`.

Comment: Does: `sudo service network-manager status` report that the service is loaded and active?

Comment: @chili555.     When I use the command     "sudo service network-manager status"    it is showing that network manager : unrecognized service

Comment: @pomsky                                  lspci - knn | grep Net - A3; rfkill list after executing that command I have got the following on the terminal as shown in below. 06:00.0 Network controller [0280] : Intel corporation wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83) subsystem: Intel corporation dual band wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470] kernel driver in use :iwlwifi 07:00.0 ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL 8102E PCI Express fast ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07) 0: phy0:wireless lan softblocked:no hard blocked: yes